# NoteText Acumatica Mobile Framework

Tags: mobile, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to add the note text to my Mobile app. I have figured out to add in the app so it is visible; however, I cannot write notes in the note text and save it. when I write a note in acumatica itself then it saves and you see the note on the mobile app. Is there a way to reverse this? Is there a way where you can write a note on the mobile site and it will save it to acumatica. Is there a way to write multiple notes on and from the mobile site or do you have to keep adding to the new one?

I am not able to embed images yet. Sorry for the links.

[What I want to add.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hziSP.png)

[Current code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNxRK.png)

[Full Code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhDdn.png)

[Android Snippet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJYdt.png)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the full code for the sm:Field element, since it is cut off in the screenshot.

I do see `Special="A"` in the screenshot, which leads me to believe it says `Special="AllowEdit"`.  That should be removed as it is used only for linking a field to its parent entity (e.g., Business Account, Inventory item).

Can you try adding `TextType="PlainMultiLine"` to the sm:Field element, and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Thank you, I tried to add Specail="AllowEdit" that only works for selector fields on forms. I also tried TextType="PlaineMultLine" it did not do anything.

Comment: It was probably a typo in your comment, but did you try `PlaineMultLine` as you mentioned above, or `PlainMultiLine` as stated in my answer?  Make sure it is spelled correctly.  If it was spelled correctly, then unfortunately it may not be possible to edit a note field in the mobile application.  Hopefully someone else might have more information on whether this is possible or not.

Comment: It was a typo in my comment; however, I just figured it out. You have to use it in its own `<sm:ContainerLink>` instead of in an `<sm:Group>`.

Comment: That is great, I am glad you figured out the problem.